# What variables best determine bicycle fit for an individual without riding it?

Tags: bike-fit, beginner

Trying to decide a bicycle purchase, not sure how to choose the best fit bike for my body type.  Should I measure my leg length, torso length, arm length, body build, does my gender make a difference?

Comment: "Gender specific" bike frame designs are generally about the leg to torso length ration of an average woman being different from an average man, so if you are measuring those, it's already covered. It can also make a difference to saddle choice, but that's a personal thing and easily changed anyway. (There's also the fact that traditional "ladies" frames have a step-through frame to make it easier to ride wearing a skirt or dress, but step-through frames can be unisex.)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that does make a major difference is the type of bike.  As a very general rule, the faster the bike is intended to be ridden, the more important the fit.  I'll address this from the point of view of what most beginners ride -- things like Euro-style city bikes, hybrids, and basic mountain bikes.

So *most* bikes that *most* beginners (based on your tags) would start riding on are quite forgiving. For a conventional geometry, leg length (i.e. seat tube length) is the biggest factor.  This is the key number in the frame size, and the frame is the most important thing to get right as there are no (cost-effective) adjustments or substitutions possible.  When cheap bikes are sized by a single number, it's usually based on this length, but comparison between makes isn't simply a matter of the length.  To some extent a too-small frame can be compensated for by raising the saddle, but it's much better to keep this for fine-tuning as too much seat post extension often results in the handlebars being too low. A frame that's too big can lead to disomfort or injury, even if you don't have to worry about a top tube.

The reach (approximately top tube+ stem length) and stack (handlebar height) are secondary.  They scale with the seat tube so should be about right for a typically-proportioned person. Both are also quite adjustable, though to get the most adjustment means swapping out parts.

The effect of this is that most people can buy a flat-bar bike based on top-tube height / frame size alone, and only worry about anything more than the most basic adjustments when they start considering longer rides.  Of course extra care is needed if you have back/leg etc. problems.

Comment: I think you have this the wrong way round. 
Seat tube is no longer the primary way of sizing a bike. I *personally* consider it the secondary way of sizing. I always look at HTT and Reach first.

Comment: @OraNob even with googling (in case my assumption was wrong) I see that as a road bike thing, and there's no reason to assume road bikes from the question

Comment: Compact and semi-compact may be akin to road bike geometry - but on any bike - you should be looking at the top-tube length / reach. And especially on mountain bike - the seat tube length varies hugely with frame design.

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but how can seat tube length be the biggest factor when the seatpost makes it adjustable anyway?

Comment: @stijn maybe I could have been clearer on the effect it has on the rest of the frame size. But also if the seat tube is too long, nothing you can do will make the bike smaller. If it's much too short, an extra long seat post would get that right but the bike still wouldn't fit.

Comment: A seat height has far more latitude for adjustment. Typically a seatpost can be upto 50cm long. Cockpit length can only be adjusted with stem length from 5cm to about 12cm - and even then this will affect the handling of the bike. So cockpit length is critical when sizing the bike and is the first and foremost measurement for sizing a bike. They are NOT secondary measurements to seat tube length,

Comment: @OraNob but cockpit length is much more a matter of preference -- road bikes excluded, i.e. assuming a relaxed sitting position.  To me a beginner Q that doesn't specify road-bike requires that assumption.

Comment: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-sizing.html


Top Tube Length: More Important Than Seat Tube Length!


"When people speak of bicycle frame sizes, they generally speak in terms of the seat tube length. As mentioned above, this used to be the only variable, but with proportional sizing it no longer is. I would submit that seat tube height is no longer the most important frame dimension. More determinant of the actual way the rider will sit on the bike is the top tube length."

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal ETT - Effective Top Tube 
And Reach 
are the most *critical* - they are basically sizes for the cockpit of the bicycle.
The old and traditional way of measuring the seat-tube is now almost redundant since the creation of the compact and semi-compact frame geometry.

In this kind of geometry the cockpit size lengthens with the height of the seatpost. It effectively allows a fewer bicycle sizes to cater for a greater range of rider heights. Which in turn can also save on manufacturing costs. And *can* allow a rider to ride a smaller / lighter frame.

Seat-tube is a way to measure clearance over the top bar of the bike - and in this instance better measured centre of BB to centre of top tube.

Comment: Stack can be just as important as reach for many rides.  Not everyone can ride a bike with small stack size, even though the reach may be a match.

Answer (score 1):

This article on my blog discusses some of the basics of "bike fit"

https://audaxing.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/long-distance-ride-bike-fit-tips/

Steve Hogg has some great ideas about this area and it's well worth reading anything by him

http://www.cyclingnews.com/features/the-anatomy-of-bike-position/

The info above is generally about "racing" bikes with drop bars

Comment: I like linked material but for it to be a complete answer you need to summarize and interpret the material you linked. SE Answers need to stand alone, links are used to give recognition, as a cite or to provide additional reading material.